# In Angular 8, i have problem with overlapping of components in angular .Header component is overlapping child component? how to overcome?

Tags: angular, overlapping-instances

In Angular 8, i have problem with overlapping of components in angular .Header component is overlapping child component? how to overcome **strong text**

Answer (score 0):

So, I think you should look into a couple of things:

1. Have a look at your Component's encapsulation (the `encapsulation` property on the `@Component-decorator` configuration - per default, it's set to encapsulate (not leak styling)
2. Do you have any styling included in the `styles`-configuration of `angular.json` - it may target "too wide"

it's very difficult to help, when not having a concrete example. Hope you find it useful.